# How can I create a numbered column Excel with a new number for each unique data item?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet with two columns.

The first column is presently empty, while the second is filled with data. The number of rows is about ten thousand. I want to create numbers in the first column to match the data in the second column, as demonstrated below. How can I achieve this?

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN 2
1        AA
2        BB
2        BB
2        BB
3        C
4        DD
5        E
6        FF
7        F
7        F
7        F
7        F
7        F
8        G
8        G
8        G
```

Comment: Is column 2 always sorted?

Comment: yes it is always sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column 2 is always sorted then this simple formula approach will work.

In A2 put 1.

In A3 put this formula:

```
=IF(B3<>B2,A2+1,A2)
```

Then copy down

[image]

---

If not sorted then this slightly longer formula will do the same.

Like above put 1 in A2 and this formula in A3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A2,MATCH(B3,$B$2:$B2,0)),MAX(A$2:$A2)+1)
```

Both approaches if you do not copy and paste the values if the data gets sorted differently the values will change.

Comment: It works ... what if the second column contain number as well as text

Comment: I will not matter, It only cares if the one above in the second column is the same as the one below. @pradip.  Remember to mark as correct if this works for you.  You do that be clicking the check mark by the answer which will be available 15-20 minutes after the question was asked.